# Updating in database throws SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my SQL statement:

```
UPDATE InboxItem 
SET OrderId = @0, Item = @1, Quantity = @2, Price = @3, 
    Memo = "", InboxId = @4, VATId = @5 
WHERE Id = @6
```

This throws `SqlException`, saying that

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as \"\" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

I think I know what the problem is. If I give value to Memo, everything is ok. However, I sometimes want memo to be empty string. How to do this?

Comment: change query to this `Memo = @7` and in sql paramaters send string.empty for @7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `''` instead of `""`. Also verify that your input is escaped properly (perhaps one of the strings has a comma in it that is unescaped).

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();            
sb.Append("UPDATE InboxItem ");
sb.Append("SET OrderId = @0, Item = @1, Quantity = @2, Price = @3, ");
sb.Append("Memo = @7, InboxId = @4, VATId = @5 ");
sb.Append("WHERE Id = @6");
var cm = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Convert.ToInt16("OrderValue"));
//and so on
```